# Merging cells accross multiple rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge, cell-format

Excel has a neat feature called "Merge Across" which as the name implies, merges multiple cells into compound cells that each span two or more columns.
I would like to know if I can achieve a similar thing but instead of merging across columns, I want the compound cells to span multiple rows.

Here is an image of what I want to achieve:

[image: Image showing what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first merge & center one column by hand (in your example M4:M7), and then use "format painter" on the other columns (N4:O7). This is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: This is unapplicable if you have a lot of clolumns.

Answer (score -1):

You have probably found the answer by now, but in case someone else asks.
The Merging rows option is right there in front of you in your screen dump.  Just select the cells downwards (rows) that you want to merge (in your case M4:M7) and click the **Merge & Center** button. Or if you want to use the dropdown as shown, select the **Merge Cells** option.

You will then repeat the process for cells N4:N7 and O4:O7

[Edit: I guess there is not a ONE CLICK solution, but this is not that hard]
[5 second solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoCnR.gif)

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem as it requires several clicks instead of the efficiency of "merge across"

Comment: I haven't found the answer yet. What you proposed here, however, doesn't apply to my case as it requires selecting each column - one at at time. I want a solution where I select the whole table in one go.